# Posting answer to closed question

Tags: bug

I was able to post [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18881380/1393766) on recently closed question (take a look at posting answer time and closing time).

1. I started writing answer before question was closed.
2. Then info about closing was shown disabling "Post Your Answer" button, so I clicked on info to reload page.
3. From curiosity went "back" in my browser and previously cached version of question was loaded enabling "Post Your Answer" button.
4. After captcha validation I found my answer posted.

Is this bug or feature? Why there is no server side mechanism to check if question is closed while posting answers?